# Testing a react component with a connected child component using enzyme mount

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, react-redux, enzyme

I'm testing a react component using enzyme mount (because i'm testing it's lifecycle methods). My problem is that my component has a redux connected child component, which is giving me the error:

`Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Popup)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Popup)`

How can I get around this?
Thanks!
Uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, you need to provide your component with the store.

Either pass it through props:

```
const wrapper = mount(<PopupContainer store={store} />)
```

Or wrap it in a `<Provider>`:

```
const wrapper = mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <PopupContainer />
    </Provider>
)
```

Now, if you're using Jest and don't want the wrapped component to interfere with your test, you could mock it:

```
jest.mock('./Popup', () => 'Popup');
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to mount the component without mounting it's children.. But I guess this is the only way to solve this? Maybe mocking the store?

Comment: @UriKlar You said yourself that you're using `mount` to test lifecycle hooks, so children *will* be mounted. However, you could mock `Popup` component with a blank one.

Comment: Yes, mocking Popup would be a perfect solution! Could you possibly edit the answer to include an example of how I can go about doing that? I found this: http://engineering.pivotal.io/post/stub-dont-shallow-render-your-child-components/, so I could just stub the container component's render method. But if you have a simpler method i'd be thankful if you shared it!

Comment: @UriKlar Edited. This example relies on the fact that your container merely renders the `Popup` component. If your `render` is more complex, post your code for a better solution.

Comment: Hi Or, I'm not using using jasmine and not jest, but since this is a valid answer i'll accept it. I also found babel-plugin-rewire that can be used to mock imports but don't have time to test it right now. Thanks

Comment: @UriKlar Sorry, I assumed wrong. Back to your original idea, perhaps something like `spyOn(PopupContainer.prototype, "render").and.returnValue(null)` might work.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to mock the store. Just extract the wrapped component:

```
const WrappedPopup = Popup.WrappedComponent;
```

And test it like normal component, with mocked props and actions:

```
const wrapper = mount(<WrappedPopup connectPropA={...} actionB={...} />);
```

The wrapped component is a static property the `connect` added to the wrapper component for accessing the original component.

Comment: I'm not trying to test the Popup component. I'm trying to test a container component that Popup is one of it's children.